# $skiptoken doesnot skip and return next set of records with the Sharepoint API

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-api

We are trying to query the Sharepoint API. We are using the below query to get the top 5000 and it works.

```
  https://abc.123.org/sites/js/project/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('S%20Codes')/items?$top=5000
```

But breaks if we try to get more than 5000 records.So tried to use the $skiptoken parameter using the `link rel ="next"` from the above query as

```
/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=5175&$top=5000
```

but using that still returns only first 5000 records

I even tried this

```
  /items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=5176&$top=5000
```

hoping it would skip the first 5175 ID's and start from 5176. But no change.

We also tried to use the skip in the query parameter to get the next 5000 records and it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with using skiptoken. It should work if you use `?$skip=5000`.